# create a slack message and edit before sending

Tags: slack, botkit

I have created a bot using Botkit and am working on creating an interactive message. What I want to do is when the user clicks on the button in the interactive message, a new message will be created pulling som info from the original interactive message, BUT WILL NOT BE SENT. I need to continue editing the message before choosing to send it. Does anybody know whether this is possible or not? I have been googling and searching slack's docs and botkit's docs, but haven't been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let the user edit a message before sending you can use the [Dialog](https://api.slack.com/dialogs) feature from Slack. It will allow you to show an input text field, where the user can make his edits. I am not familiar with Botkit though and can not say if it supports Dialogs.